# How to use compositingFilter in CALayer?

Tags: ios, calayer

I just noticed that a **CALayer** can have a  **compositingFilter** as a property.

But a **compositingFilter** requires an  **inputImage** and an **inputBackgroundImage** as its inputs. Then the filter provide output image in a method.

So how should I use this filter as a property of **CALayer**? What are the inputs and output?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation for `compositingFilter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/compositingFilter)? It says "This property is not supported on layers in iOS."

Comment: Yeah, I did. However, a few such filters are available for use. I wish to know if there are more.

Comment: There are two compositingFilter that we can use (ios 5):plusL & multiply.   However, they are CAFilter, not CIFilter:
view.layer.compositingFilter = [CHClass(CAFilter) filterWithType:@"multiply"]; (code is from Ryan Petrich's displayeffects)